# NatvieScript Installation Error(windows)

Tags: nativescript

I have a problem completing NativeScript installation requirement. I got stuck at number 5 in the installation guide available [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/ns-setup-win).

When i run the command "tns doctor" in the command prompt, i get the error message below:

> Cannot find a compatible Android SDK for compilation. To be able to
>   build for An droid, install Android SDK 22 or later. Run $
>   %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android to manage your Android SDK versions.
>
> You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system.
>   You can i nstall any version in the following range: '>=23 <=27'. Run
>   $ %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android from your command-line to install
>   required An droid Build Tools.
>
> You need to have Android SDK 22 or later and the latest Android
>   Support Reposito ry installed on your system. Run $
>   %ANDROID_HOME%\tools\android to manage the Android Support Repository.

I have installed the required sdk and i am still getting the same error message and every time i execute this script in the console, it takes like forever to complete:

> "%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin\sdkmanager" "tools" "platform-tools"
>   "platforms;android-25" "build-tools;25.0.2"
>   "extras;android;m2repository" "extras;google;m2repository"

Comment: If you have Android Studio installed, make sure that the path for the SDK in Android Studio (in SDK Manager) is the same as the one set for `ANDROID_HOME`. Multiple SDK installations might cause troubles - if this is the case leave just one and make sure that ANDROID_HOME is synced to the valid path.

Comment: Thanks, i have already found solution and i have to say it was not easy at all.